# Why are spatial lagged exogeneous variables rarely used?

Tags: spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

In the publication "Regional Productivity and Income Convergence in the  Unified Germany 1992-2000" ([link](http://home.arcor.de/christiandreger/Papers/Productivity%20and%20Income%20convergence.pdf)) it is claimed without detailed explanation: "Usually,  in  spatial  econometric  models  only  spatial  lags  in  the dependent variable are taken into account, while spatial lagged exogenous variables ordinarily are not explicitly modelled." And:  "As  in  time  series  analysis  one  can  argue  that  spatial  effects  stemming  from  exogenous variables will be captured by a spatial lagged endogenous variable."

From these statements I get that both approaches are in principal equal. Is this true? If it is, why exactly is the first approach (spatially lagged endogenous/dependent variable) preferable in the spatial domain?